# Rails 4 - How to dynamically reference an unknown table related to itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In an attempt to build an automated filter system for a dynamically generated index view, I came upon the need to handle related records on the same table, (for example, a Task belongs to Tasks through a parent_id field set as the foreign key. How would one reference the self associated table?

The 'klasses' example below is the illustration in question.

```
# Compile recursive array based on parent_id, 
# where parent_id is foreign_key on it's same table 

def build_recursive(conditions)
    @children = []
    klass = current_controller.singularize.constantize.where(conditions).all

    def fetch_subs(sub)            
        sub.klasses.where(conditions).order(:sort).each do |child| <-- how to dynamically reference 'klasses'?
            @children << child
            fetch_subs(child)
        end
        return @children
    end

    klass.klasses.each do |record|  <-- how to dynamically reference 'klasses'? 
        @children << record
        fetch_subs(record)  
    end

    return @children
end
```

How would one dynamically reference 'klasses' in this example, where klasses would be the related and same table of the current controller?

Also, if there is an existing gem or better solution altogether, I would gratefully accept additional suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you think something like that https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry will fit into your schema?

Comment: Mikhail, in looking at this gem so far, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work for what I'm attempting. I think I will pursue it and thank you for the pointer!

Comment: The ancestry gem was a great solution and worked well. It allowed me to use '.children' where I was asking about 'klasses' above. Thanks again.

Comment: I will go ahead and add this as answer, so you can close this question.

Comment: Sounds great. I'll watch for your post and close it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look for [ancetry gem](http://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) it will let you manage parent->children relations with ease.